# How to change the Language to japanese in the Language Bar dynamically on for a windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

How to change the Language to Japanese in the Language Bar dynamically on for  a C# windows application.

Should I use some script to invoke language settings or is there any other better way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting CurrentInputLanguage:

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP"));
```

Comment: A question, what do you do, it the application does change the input, but the Language Bar still shows the earlier language, like **EN** instead of **JA**. See post on this please: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37314482/6201755